# Nested sed (sed in sed)

Tags: bash, sed, nested

I want to extract the number of hostname (like `Server01` => `01`) and store this as a part of string into a file.

Unfortunatelly it still doesn't work. The last try looks like:

```
sed s/TRUNKNUMBER/0812345`hostname | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`/ -i sipgate.xml
```

But the result is, TRUNKNUMBER is removed, instead replaced by number like '081234501'.

What did I wrong? Also I want to know how to count the chars if sed-error is given like

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'
```

UPDATE1:
Sure I can further informations. I thought it's clear, but sorry.

```
floh@Host01:~$ hostname
Host01
floh@Host01:~$ cat sipgate.xml
<extension name="sipgate">
 <condition field="destination_number" expression="^TRUNKNUMBER">
  ...
 </condition>
</extension>
</extension>
```

As I wrote I want to replace "TRUNKNUMBER" in sipgate.xml by a string concated by "0812345" + Number of Hostname.

With the one sed-command I can extract the number of hostname:

```
floh@Host01:~$ hostname | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'
01
```

This is fine, now I tried with:

```
sed s/TRUNKNUMBER/0812345`hostname | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`/ -i sipgate.xml
```

Then I got:

```
floh@Host01:~$ cat sipgate.xml
<extension name="sipgate">
 <condition field="destination_number" expression="^">
  ...
 </condition>
</extension>
</extension>
```

Which is not good because I expected '...expression="^081234501">' in the second line.

Comment: If you show your input and the expected output, it's a lot easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: not sure I understand what you're attempting; please update the question with example input (results of `hostname`), a couple sample lines from `sipgate.xml` and the desired output

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I added further information as UPDATE1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found out the command was already ok:

```
sed s/TRUNKNUMBER/0812345`hostname | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`/ -i sipgate.xml
```

The result was "wrong" because I acidentally reused the source-file which didn't had the string `TRUNKNUMBER`. (Obviously I forgot to restore the source-file for that try)

Now I learned that I should remove -i next time in order to test the output instead trying to modify the file.

Again I'm sorry!
Floh